# spring security Authentication and resource server seprated check_token is not sending authorization header (outh2 jwt spring boot, zuul)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

**problem**

resource server making request for check_token its not passing authorization token which is implemented by spring security. how we can pass authorization token for /check_token endpoint?

**I am using zuul as api gateway and all request go through zuul only.
i created auth server which is authentication server (spring cloud project) 
and code is given below for authorization and i register authenticationManager with webSecurityConfigurationAdapter 
code is given below**

AuthorizationServerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Value("${config.oauth2.tokenTimeout}")
    private int expiration;

    @Value("${config.oauth2.privateKey}")
    private String privateKey;

    @Value("${config.oauth2.publicKey}")
    private String publicKey;

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient("client")
                .secret(passwordEncoder().encode("secret"))
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password", "refresh_token", "authorization_code")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(expiration)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(expiration);

    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {


        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(privateKey);

        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Value("${filters.cors.allowed.origin}")
    private String allowedOriginUrlForCordFilter;

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true); 
        config.addAllowedOrigin(allowedOriginUrlForCordFilter);
        //config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:8080/");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(accessTokenConverter());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    /**
     * Defines the authorization and token endpoints and the token services
     * @param endpoints
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        endpoints
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .tokenServices(tokenServices())
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }
}
```

**resource server  another spring cloud project which is basically our business services
and for further communication i need authorization token this code is implement by using filter i implemented.**

ResourceServerConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    // private static final Logger LOGGER =
    // Logger.getLogger(ResourceServerConfiguration.class);

    @Value("${config.oauth2.publicKey}")
    private String publicKey;

    @Value("${config.oauth2.privateKey}")
    private String privateKey;

    @Value("${config.oauth2.resource.id}")
    private String resourceId;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().anonymous().disable().authorizeRequests()
                // .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                // .antMatchers("/oauth/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/register/**").authenticated();
    }

    // @Override
    // public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
    // resources.resourceId(resourceId).tokenServices(tokenServices()).tokenStore(tokenStore());
    // }

    // @Bean
    // @Primary
    // public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
    // DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    // defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
    // defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
    // defaultTokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(accessTokenConverter());
    // return defaultTokenServices;
    // }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {

        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(privateKey);

        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public RemoteTokenServices tokenServices() {
        final RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
    tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("http://localhost:8765/auth/oauth/check_token/");
        tokenService.setClientId("client");
        tokenService.setClientSecret("secret");
        //tokenService.setTokenName("");
        // tokenService.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        // tokenService.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenService.setAccessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
        return tokenService;
    }
}
```

**now issue is when resource server making request for check_token there i am anable to pass authorization token.**

Comment: what do you mean by "unable to pass authorization token"?

Comment: @NatFar IN RemoteTokenService we have to give url of authorization server which will check token is valid or not. here authorization token it's not passing in this request.